# How can I share data between operating system in Virtual Box and actual operating system ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu installed on my PC. I have also installed Virtual Box in which I have installed windows XP.

I've given only 30 GB of space for my data (photos, music and videos) in the home folder of Ubuntu.  I want to share that data (Folder) to XP so that I can play songs in XP too.

Please give any solution to make it possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a [Howto](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15868) in the [VirtualBox forums](http://forums.virtualbox.org):

> After installing the Guest Additions,
>   you can use the Shared Folders
>   Functionality. To access them, you
>   have to define at least one in the VM
>   settings. Open the VM Settings and go
>   to Shared Folders. You can define them
>   there. Click on the Add button and
>   browse for a folder you want to share.
>   Make sure that the name of the share
>   doesn't contain any illegal characters
>   like white spaces. Keep the name as
>   simple as possible. In this howto, I
>   will use the name share.
>
> Now that you have defined a SF, it's
>   time to mount it. Boot the Guest and
>   open a terminal. Create a folder where
>   you will mount it on. E.g. in your
>   home folder. I will use ~/host for the
>   mount point. Now mount it with the
>   following command:
>
> ```
> sudo mount -t vboxsf share ~/host
> ```
>
> Note that with this, the default mount
>   options are used and all files are
>   owned by root. This can be changed by
>   adding some mount options. Options are
>   passed on with the -o parameter. You
>   can use multiple options with one
>   parameter, seperate the values with a
>   comma. See the man page of mount for
>   more info on which options you can
>   use. The User Manual also notes the
>   options compatible with the Shared
>   Folders. To mount the SF so that you
>   are the owner of the files, use this
>   command:
>
> ```
> sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 share ~/host
> ```
>
> If you want to have it mount
>   automatically upon each boot, put the
>   mount command in /etc/rc.local (Debian
>   based distro's), or whatever script is
>   run at the end of the boot process.
>   The Shared Folders service should
>   mount them automatically, but that
>   doesn't always happen. Using
>   /etc/fstab has little effect, because
>   that file is processed before the SF
>   module is loaded and will fail to
>   mount the share. Sometimes, the share
>   does get mounted because the GA check
>   for it when they are loaded upon boot,
>   but it's very flaky, meaning it
>   doesn't work most of the time. You're
>   better of with the first option. When
>   you put the mount command in
>   /etc/rc.local, so it's mounted at
>   startup, you can't use the short
>   notation for your home folder. During
>   startup, everything is done through
>   the root user, so using ~ for home,
>   means it's the home folder of Root
>   (/root). Change it to the full path.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> mount -t vboxsf share /home/<username>/host
> ```